# Cannot Export JDL from Latest JHipster 6.5.0. Error show "Cannot read property 'error' of undefined"

Tags: jhipster

I have updated to latest Jhipster 6.5.0. I have seen that the export option is not working 
Below is the error message that I get. Even with -d (debug) option, nothing much is getting printed

```
C:\ap\ap>jhipster -d export-jdl C:\ap\export-ap.jdl
INFO! Using JHipster version installed locally in current project's node_modules
INFO! Debug logging is on
DEBUG!  cmd: export-jdl
DEBUG!  args: C:\ap\export-ap.jdl, commands: Object, options: Object, _execs: Object, _allowUnknownOption: true, _args: Object, _name: export-jdl, _noHelp: false, parent: Object, _description: Create a JDL file from the existing entities, _argsDescription: undefined, _events: Object, _eventsCount: 1
DEBUG!  opts: argument: Object, desc: Create a JDL file from the existing entities
DEBUG!  Arguments found
DEBUG!  cmdArgs: C:\ap\export-ap.jdl
INFO! Executing jhipster:export-jdl C:\ap\export-ap.jdl
INFO! Options: d: export-jdl, from-cli: true
ERROR! TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined
```

Comment: What does print `node --version` ? Are you using an LTS version of node as recommended in JHipster doc?

Comment: it is fixed in generator-jhipster 6.5.1, or you can upgrade to JHipster core 6.0.4 in your package.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. This is fixed is new Version of JHipster... Thanks for update